# Alarms are not working

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, alarm, clock, lenovo

I've been facing the issue of missing alarms for a week. I can set alarms successfully, it displays in notification but not running.

Though if I try to check it will have work or not by setting alarms after 1-2 minutes, then it works ok. But if I set alarm before sleeping then it doesn't ring on morning.

One another thing may be related: I'm getting "Unfortunately clock has stopped" alert randomly about 2-3 times in a day (though it is not happening exactly while setting alarms).

So, I'm not getting what's going wrong with alarms. How can I recognize the issue and fix it?

Note: Running (non-rooted as running under time period of warranty) Android 6.0 on Lenovo .

Comment: Not sure, but could it be you've "dozed" the alarms app (or something related)? Btw: Never heard there's an Android 6.20. Must be something Lenovo specific :)

Comment: @Izzy I've disabled only calculator (also "force stop" would not be case as I've tried reboting several times). Btw was typo.

Comment: Could you be specific about your device model?  Are you using only the stock Clock app?  Have you tried clearing the data for that app?

Comment: @MatthewRead Lenovo A6600 Plus. Yes, using only stock Clock app. Ok I've cleared data now let me check for next alarm.

Comment: @MatthewRead Clearing data worked. Now alarms are working fine and "unfortunately clock has stopped" message has gone permanently!

Comment: Excellent!  It's always nice when that works straight off.  I've turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing the data for your Clock app.